# Connecting a backend to GoogleBigQuery

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, google-bigquery

I have a large data set in google BigQuery that I need to access in my backend. In order to that I need to install Google Cloud SDK, however, the current service I'm using (Heroku) seems to not allow that. Is it possible to do this with an AWS server or should I look into using Google's server solution? Or is there a way around this so I can still use heroku? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That doesn't sound right that you can't use a SDK (library dependancy) on Heroku. Are you sure you got that right? I'm not sure what language you are using, but for example, it's doable with Python - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu I need to be able to run these commands, however, heroku says

`bash: sudo: command not found`

Comment: That's something completely different. Have a look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23572/bash-sudo-command-not-found

Comment: I don't think it is though, because I also can't install packages. It says something along the lines of this is a read only file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) provides commandline tools to manage your Google Cloud project resources. Under the hood, the SDK uses the standard [REST APIs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/) to connect with your cloud project resources such as your BigQuery datasets.

Therefore, if you are not able to install the GCloud SDK on your Heroku machine due to missing permissions, you can instead directly run the [BigQuery APIs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) from a [simple program](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/master/bigquery) that [Heroku is actually meant to run](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/python) (such as with [Python](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-usage.html)).

By using the [Google Client Libraries](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/), you can directly connect to your Google Cloud project resources from any of the supported languages running on any backend machine.